# What exactly is anti-pattern in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a parent component.

Parent.js

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  someMethod () {
    LoadDataforChild();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Child someMethod={this.someMethod}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js (Child is pure component)

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.someMethod();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello child
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am quite unaware of anti-patterns in react. I called parent method in Child(pure component). Is this an anti-pattern? And what exactly is an anti-pattern in terms of parent and child components?

Comment: The child component is not a pure component in this case as you extends `React.Component`.

Comment: I apologise, correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the your question to Anti patterns in reactjs, i would like to answer widely as i can basing on off.docs, articles and on my own experience:

- **do not store a component in component's state or a store (f.e. redux store)**

```
    //REDUX REDUCER
    const initialState = {
        isHOCOpened: false,
        child: null
      }

    export default reducer = (state = initialState, {type, content}) => {
        switch (type) {
          case ('openHOC'): {
            const updatedState = {...state};
            updatedState.isHOCOpened = true;
            updatedState.child = content;
            return {
              ...state, ...updatedState
            }
        ...
    }

    //PARENT COMPONENT
    ...some other imports;
    import  ChildElement from './ChildElement';
    export default class ParentElement extends Component {
      ...some code...
      render() {
        const { openHOC, HOCcontent } = this.props;
        return (
          <div onClick={()=>this.openHOC(<ChildElements/>)}>
            <HOCElement/>
          </div>
    }

    //HIGHER ORDER COMPONENT
    export default const HOC = ({isHOCOpened, child}) => {
      ...some code...
      return (
        <div>
          {isOpened && {children}}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Recommended way is

```
    ...some other imports;
    import  ChildElement from './ChildElement';
    export default class ParentElement extends Component {
      state = {
        isHOCOpened: false,
      }

      openHOC = () => this.setState({openHOC: true});

      render() {
        return (
          <div onClick={this.openHOC}>
            {isOpened && <HOCElement/><ChildElement/></HOCElement>}
          </div>
      }
    }

    ...
    export default const HOC = ({children}) => {
      ...some stuff...
      return (
        <div>{children}</div>
      )
```

Organize your app logic that avoiding storing components in state/store;

- **do not pass setState right in events** as above:

```
    onClick={() => {
      //some code
      this.setState({isOpened: true})
    }
```

Better take it away the event and store it solely as the example before:

```
      openHOC = () => {
        //some code
        return this.setState({openHOC: true})
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div onClick={this.openHOC}>
            {isOpened && <HOCElement/><ChildElement/></HOCElement>}
          </div>
      }
```

It affects performance because it creates the function every time, but this touches overall understanding of JS, to ReactJS only. Check out the article for a more in-depth discussion on [this](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578).;

- **do not bind every time passing the props variable** if you link it to environment where the variable to be executed:

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: ''
        };
      }

      updateValue(evt) {
        this.setState({
          name: evt.target.value
        });
      }

   render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)} value={this.state.name} />    
      </form>
    )
      }
    }
```

instead bind all vars in the constructor function:

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: ''
        };
        this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
    }
```

- **do not use indexes as keys prop**:

```
    <ul>
      {liArray.map( (e,i) => <li key={i}>{e.text}</li>}
    </ul>
```

It's not exactly antipattern but straight buggy code and unexpected results. As it's been written a lot of times in [off docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), React uses Keys to track changes in DOM tree and redraw it, so Keys must be unique in spite of indexes are changes to its array position;
Put unique props as ids or anything else `{liArray.map(e => <li key={e.id}>{e.text}</li>}`

- one more antipattern **do not compute values right in setState**:
  `setState({value: this.state.counter + passedValue})`
  Do to before calling setState:

```
    updateValue(passedValue) {
       const result = this.state.counter + passedValue;
       setState({value: result})
    }
```

- **do not pass a function behind the setState** expecting to execute it right after the setState:

```
      updateValue(value) {
        this.setState({counter: value});
        this.addToCounter(1)
      }
```

because setState is asynchronous [check it](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)
Pass it as a second argument in setState to get it run as the component is get new state:

```
      updateValue(value) {
        this.setState(
          {counter: value},
          ()=>this.addToCounter(1)
        )
      }
```

- and the last **do not name a component with a lowercase letter**. React smart enough :) to recognize to want to pass a html tag or a react component:
  This will not work:`<mycomponent>content</mycomponent>` but this do the trick `<Mycomponent>content</MyComponent>`. The same will be with *Button* and *button*;

Comment: Why redux? it would be better for react without using redux.

Comment: @TomSawyer i tried to cover a bit more complicated situations but just react state. This question is asked to help newcomers to avoid hard mistakes from the start and i tried to cover more than just a simple app case.

Answer (score 1):

There is not so much of anti pattern in general as there is a definite use case for having data fetching in the parent - think multiple children etc. But typically that is done through a callback such as when a user clicks a button rather than on mount.

In your example, it would make more sense to pass data directly to the child as a prop and handle the data loading in the parent's mount event.

Note, you should probably avoid using `componentWillMount()` as that is an anti pattern. Use `componentDidMount()` instead. [Read here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)